# Why wheat flour weighting more than raw wheat?

Tags: mass

I had 5 kg of raw wheat. After made it as a flour its weight become 5.3 kg. Why it's weight increased?

Answer (score 3):

If it  is not an error in your measurements, I would look at moisture content of wheat grains with respect to wheat flour.

> [The simple air-oven method](https://www.ndsu.edu/faculty/simsek/wheat/flour.html) is sufficiently accurate for the routine analysis of flour moisture at the flour mill or bakery. The procedure involves heating a small sample of flour (~2g) for 1 hr at 266˚F (130˚C + 1˚C) and taking the loss in weight as the moisture content.
>
> The moisture content of the flour is important for two reasons. First, the higher the moisture content, the lower the amount of dry solids in the flour. Flour specifications usually limit the flour moisture to 14% or less. It is in the miller’s interest to hold the moisture as close to 14% as possible. Secondly, flour with greater than 14% moisture is not stable at room temperature. Organisms naturally present in the flour will start to grow at high moistures, producing off odors and flavors.

You could repeat the test in the link  above for the same weight in grain and flour and see the difference in water content. That could explain your observation, if for example, the flour has  moisture 14% and in the equal weight grain moisture  is 5% it would explain within errors your numbers.

Moisture seems a reasonable guess, think of how easily one makes a paste out of flour, but not out of grain: the grain is protected of moisture by the outer layer .